# Possible DNS issue affecting only one machine on our network

Tags: domain-name-system, internet-explorer

Alice uses a marketing site that requires IE 11 and Compatibility Mode. Occasionally, when Alice attempts to access the site, it times out. When this occurs, the only fix is to log into our domain controller and reset the DNS cache (on the domain controller). Resetting the DNS cache immediately resolves her issue for a few weeks or so.

Other info:
She is running Windows 7 and IE 11 (updated/patched). Other identical machines in her office have no problems accessing the site. This issue has been ongoing for a couple of months. Other troubleshooting steps include:

- clearing her local cache
- rejoining her to the domain
- resetting and configuring IE again
- and more

If I manually set her DNS locally to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, the site is immediately accessible, but this isnt really a fix.

Comment: Do you have overlapping DNS name space? Is your internal and external domain name the same? mycompany.com? From internal does it resolve if you prefix the site with 'www'?

Comment: It sounds to me like this sites DNS servers occasionally don't respond and your DNS servers will negatively cache the lack of response, clearing the cache on the DNS server will clear that and it will tben go and do another lookup. What doesn't add up with that is that other machines would have the same issue, but the client cache could mask that. Next time you have the issue I'd try and flush the cache on one of the other PC's and see if you can break it there as well. If you can't it doesn't really make sense that clearing the cache on the DNS server resolves the issue.

Comment: Its also worth mentioning that if you're using a proxy the proxy server will do the DNS lookup not the users PC.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer the  question about overlapping domain space. Our internal and external domains are not the same.

Comment: Also, when you have the issue, do a nslookup on the domain and see what the response is. Then do any other troubleshooting steps you like, and clear the cache. Once it is fixed, try another nslookup to see what it resolves as then.